# "Cannot implicitly convert type IDbConnection to SqlConnection"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, unity-game-engine

I need some help please.

I tried make an `INSERT` into my SQL database but I can't because give me an error in this code line:

```
 commandoSQL.Connection = dbcon;
```

I get this error:

> Assets/NGUI/Scripts/Interaction/ChamarVariavel.cs(43,29): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Data.IDbConnection' to`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Thanks

My code:

```
public class ChamarVariavel : MonoBehaviour {

    public UISlider slider;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    void OnGUI(){
        // Connection DB
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=******;Password=*******";

        IDbConnection dbcon;

        dbcon= new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        dbcon.Open();
        //DB Online

        float x = slider.value * 100;
        GUI.Label(new Rect( 570, 238, 70, 30 ), "(" + x.ToString("f2") + ")");

        string qInsert = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO Fuel (fuel) VALUES ('{0}')", x);

        SqlCommand commandoSQL = new SqlCommand(qInsert);

        commandoSQL.Connection = dbcon;

        try
        {
            commandoSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect( 300, 40, 300, 300 ), ex.ToString());
        }

        dbcon.Close();
        //DB offline
    }
}
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the insert - it has to do with the assignment to the `Connection` property. Take a peak at the related questions. You should be able to get away with a cast (`commandoSQL.Connection = (SqlConnection)dbcon;`), since it was created as `new SqlConnection(connectionString)`, although using a better typed variable (`var` or `SqlConnection`) would avoid that entirely.

Comment: @user2864740 You pretty much answered his question in a comment.  If you actually answer it then it possibly gives you points, but also makes it easier for people to see the correct answer and the code formatting looks better etc.  But yeah you are right ;-)

Comment: I would recommend using the CreateComman method from the IDbConnection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.createcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is literally telling you the problem, you need to *explicitly cast* the object because the `SqlCommand` is looking for a `SqlConnection`, consider doing this:

```
new SqlCommand(qInsert, (SqlConnection)dbcon);
```

and remove this line:

```
commandoSQL.Connection = dbcon;
```

Another option is to just define `dbcon` as a `SqlConnection`:

```
SqlConnection dbcon
```

and then you could do this:

```
new SqlCommand(qInsert, dbcon);
```

Finally, have a look at a [blog post](http://learncsharp.org/how-to-properly-and-safely-access-a-database-with-ado-net/) I wrote a while back; you need to change how you're using your objects.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly, is solved. And by the way congrats the blog is nice, i like it.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

an alternative approach there, which helps generalize your data access code a bit: let the connection create the command:

```
using(var commandoSQL = dbcon.CreateCommand()) {
    commandoSQL.CommandText = SQL;
    //..
}
```

In other news: use parameters, not string.Format. SQL injection is a huge problem.

Answer (score 4):

Well this would work:

```
commandoSQL.Connection = (SQLConnection)dbcon;
```

Because `dbcon` is declared as an IDBConnection but is actually a SQL connection but that is a bit daft.

Simply do

```
var dbcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

and remove

```
IDbConnection dbcon;
```

and it will be declared as the correct type. There is no reason I can see why it needs to by declared as IDBconnection.

Comment: Using 'var' is indeed the preferred way to declare dbcon as the compiler will always pick the correct type (var is not like the old Variant type in VB6). If for some reason the type underlying SqlConnection should change or be renamed (it could happen), your code still compiles/works.